# Nopcommerce RegisterRoutes

Tags: c#, nopcommerce

Hi I have problem with routes in plugin, in nopcommerce 3.6

I have in folder Controller TestPohodaController.cs contains method ImportProductInfo()

There is my RegisterRoutes:

```
namespace Nop.Plugin.Test.Pohoda
{
    public partial class RouteProvider : IRouteProvider
    {
        public void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.MapRoute("Plugin.Test.Pohoda.ImportProductInfo",
                  "Plugins/TestPohoda/ImportProductInfo",
                  new { controller = "TestPohoda", action = "ImportProductInfo" },
                  new[] { "Nop.Plugin.Test.Pohoda.Controllers" }
            );
        }
        public int Priority
        {
            get
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Installation to nopCommerce is ok, but when I go to mypage/Plugins/TestPohoda/ImportProductInfo page return 404.

I need url of TestPohodaController to call this controller from economic system. Can You help me please? Thanks.

Comment: show your controller. If you are using a custom viewengine then make sure to provide the correct view path or simply return the full path of the view like this in the action result method `return View("~/Plugins/Your_Plugin_Name/Views/TestPohoda/ImportProductInfo.cshtml");`

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET MVC Routing evaluates routes from top to bottom. So if two routes match, the first one it hits (the one closer to the 'top' of the RegisterRoutes method) will take precedence over the subsequent one.

With that in mind, you need to do two things to fix your problem:

Your default route should be at the bottom.
Your routes need to have constraints on them if they contain the same number of segments:
What's the difference between:

example.com/1
and

example.com/index
To the parser, they contain the same number of segments, and there's no differentiator, so it's going to hit the first route in the list that matches.

To fix that, you should make sure the routes that use ProductIds take constraints:

```
routes.MapRoute(
"TestRoute",
"{id}",
new { controller = "Product", action = "Index3", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
new { id = @"\d+" } //one or more digits only, no alphabetical characters
);
```

Comment: he is already using a specific url, this will not match with any other url in the default routes. your answer is totally irrelevant

Comment: i'm just giving an example to him

Comment: you are giving this as an answer (you should read terms and conditions of SO) to his question and your answer is not even correct. Your defined route is totally wrong as you don't have any url defined but only an optional parameter. this platform is to help people on their specific problems to find solutions. Not to mislead them with false or irrelevant information. You also gave me vote down just because I gave you a fair vote down. this is not even ethic. Your purpose here shouldnt be just to get some extra points but to help people.

Answer (score 0):

- You don't need to start with Plugins for your route url. it is enough
  to follow this pattern {controller}/{Action}/{parameter}
- Make sure also namespace for the controller is correct as you define
  in the routing. Nop.Plugin.Test.Pohoda.Controllers
- You can define an optional productId parameter as well. so it will
  work for mypage/TestPohoda/ImportProductInfo or
  mypage/TestPohoda/ImportProductInfo/123
- You can also set the priority higher than 0 which is priority of the
  default routeprovider in the nop.web. this way you ensure that your
  plugin reads it first. Indeed it is not necessary as you have
  specific url. this is only required if you have similar route url

Try using this route

```
 namespace Nop.Plugin.Test.Pohoda
    {
        public partial class RouteProvider : IRouteProvider
        {
            public void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
            {
                routes.MapRoute("Plugin.Test.Pohoda.ImportProductInfo",
                      "TestPohoda/ImportProductInfo/{productId}",
                      new { controller = "TestPohoda", action = "ImportProductInfo" , productId = = UrlParameter.Optional },
                      new[] { "Nop.Plugin.Test.Pohoda.Controllers" }
                );
            }
            public int Priority
            {
                get
                {
                    return 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

We will have a look at how to register plugin routes. ASP.NET routing is responsible for mapping incoming browser requests to particular MVC controller actions. You can find more information about routing here. So follow the next steps:

If you need to add some custom route, then create RouteProvider.cs file. It informs the nopCommerce system about plugin routes. For example, the following RouteProvider class adds a new route which can be accessed by opening your web browser and navigating to http://www.yourStore.com/Plugins/PaymentPayPalStandard/PDTHandler URL (used by PayPal plugin):

```
 public partial class RouteProvider : IRouteProvider
{
    public void RegisterRoutes(IRouteBuilder routeBuilder)
    {
         routeBuilder.MapRoute("Plugin.Payments.PayPalStandard.PDTHandler", "Plugins/PaymentPayPalStandard/PDTHandler",
         new { controller = "PaymentPayPalStandard", action = "PDTHandler" });
    }
    public int Priority
    {
        get
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be cache problem, try to restart IIS
actually you do nota have to register route by default you can call your method
/TestPohoda/ImportProductInfo